Inquiry Regarding Support for Intermediate Certificates in SROS 2
I am currently exploring the safety features of SROS 2 to ensure safe communication within the robotic system. One of the security aspects that interests me is the support for intermediate credentials in SROS 2.
I would like to ask whether SROS 2 supports the use of intermediate certificates? If anyone can answer my question, hopefully it can tell me how to configure and exploit effectively within the SROS 2 framework.
Additionally, I would be interested in learning about best practices or experiences related to credential management in SROS 2 deployments.
